# LibUsbDotNet Barcode scanner

Tags: barcode-scanner, libusb

I have a barcode scanner. and i successfully generated the .inf for my scanner, and it install successfully. and i tried [sample code](http://libusbdotnet.sourceforge.net/V2/html/9926451f-29bf-4fae-9233-f6467ed072c7.htm), but i keep getting *IoTimedOut:IoTimedOut:No more bytes!* . Is it because of my configuration, interface or endpoint problem?

Thanks you

this is my scanner configuration from the LibUSBDotNet, [scanner.jpg](http://i39.tinypic.com/1h9hqb.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

That sample code will timeout after 5 seconds if no input was read. In other words, you did not scan a barcode within 5 seconds of starting the application.